# How do I load/board a ship?

Tags: cortex-command

Two of the 4 scenario battles available in Cortex Command contain a step requiring you to load something onto a ship, or to escape on a ship.

[image: "Load into a ship!" ...But how?]

...How do I actually do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to open the doors of the ship. When selected, firing will open them, firing again will close. You'll see small dotted line coming from both side of the doors. If your ship is empty, any actor passing between these lines will be pulled in. Then, you can send the ship pack in orbit.

The safest way to grab an actor is to use a dropship, rather than a rocket. With a dropship, you can just open the doors, then grab your actor from above. With a rocket, you ave to open the doors, set the AI to stay, then select the actor to bring him into the ship.

[image: Dropship with open doors]

[image: A soldier getting pulled into the dropship]

Comment: Well, that wasn't intuitive at all.  I always ended up stopping at these segments of the missions.  Thanks.